# Octave Error: fun(0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals

Tags: octave

I'm attempting to run a density functional theory geometry optimization with the following script:

```
xyzToIonposOpt water.xyz 15
```

however, this relatively simple command returns the following error:

```
error: fun(0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals
error: called from
    fminsearch>nmsmax at line 275 column 8
    fminsearch at line 165 column 25
    .tmp.m at line 43 column 8
```

here is line 275 of fminsearch.m:

```
  f(1) = dirn * fun (x, varargin{:});
```

and line 165

```
  [x, exitflag, output] = nmsmax (fun, x0, options, varargin{:});
```

A similar issue is described here: https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Issue-with-fminsearch-function-td4693803.html It seems to be an issue with Octave. however, I am not certain how to workaround this issue as I am not sure where the fminsearch function is called.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how do you call the DFT? use f=dft(f,N,dim), if you don't use N and dim, you may face such errors.

Comment: can you use the FFT version instead? could you please publish all your code?

Comment: Sorry,  it seems I was not clear in my writing! I meant Density Functional Theory, not discrete Fourier transform! I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: What is `xyzToIonposOpt`? It is not part of Octave. Please read [mre], we cannot help you if we don't know what is happening inside your scripts.

Comment: xyzToIonposOpt is part of the density functional theory software that I am using.

Comment: I'm attempting to follow this tutorial: http://jdftx.org/CoulombTrunc.html

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a service to debug third party software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires debugging of third part software http://jdftx.org.

Comment: Is there no way to adjust the Octave script to fix this error? If not, could you at least help me understand why this is happening and why I can't fix it?

Comment: You can fix, but you need to show more code and explain what version of octave you are running. You can also open an issue with the developers at  https://github.com/shankar1729/jdftx/issues. I suggest also you to read https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Debugging.html#Debugging